# Не работает flex-box. Конкретно:justify-content: center

Tags: css, html5

```css
.header{
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="background-color: blanchedalmond;justify-content: center;">
<div><h2>Управление Ротаторами</h2></div>
</div>
```

Хочу что бы заголовок был по центру, но он все еще прижат к левому краю. Не понимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: в коде не хватает одного закрывающего `<div>`. вы понимаете разницу между между `flex` и `inline-flex`?

Comment: да понимаю, и с div все нормально. если я ошибаюсь, поправьте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

У вас `.header` строчный элемент из-за того, что вы даете ему `inline-flex`. И он не занимает всю ширину родителя, а имеет ширину `auto`, т.е. ширину на основе ширин вложенных элементов, т.е. вашего залоговка. И, соответственно, заголовок выровнять относительно `.header` невозможно, т.к. он занимает всю ширину родителя. Можно выравнить `.header`, способами для строчных элементов, в частности для родителя `.header` (в данном случае `body`) нужно дать `text-align: center`.

```css
.header {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="background-color: blanchedalmond;justify-content: center;">
  <div>
    <h2>Управление Ротаторами</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но вероятно вы не так все задумали... Поэтому:

```css
.header {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.header div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="background-color: blanchedalmond;justify-content: center;">
  <div>
    <h2>Управление Ротаторами</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```